# Set writeConcern level to unacknowledged in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a huge mongodb database and due to the fact that only one thread is writing in a collection at any given time and all the updates are performed on documents that already exist, I'd like mongodb to not acknowledge any operation because I want to boost performance.

I came across a writeConcern rundown [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) but I have no idea how apply use the unacknowledged write concern on updates in pymongo.

Note: I'm using pymongo 2.7.1, python 3.4 and mongo 2.6.3

**Edit**: I'd like to add the [bulk version](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html#write-concern) of modified write concern update to Neil Lunn's solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this in either one of two places.

1. Either when obtaining the initial MongoClient:

   ```python
   client = MongoClient(w=0)
   ```
2. Or when issuing statements as an additional argument:

   ```python
   result = db.collection.update({ 'a': 1 }, { 'a': 2 }, w=0 )
   ```

Both are valid places to specify a write concern. What you specify on MongoClient is "global" for the connection and the other statements override where used or otherwise just use the "global".

Comment: Thanks a lot. It proved harder to find than it usually is.